# RealmResults.clear() throwing NotSupportedException

Tags: android, realm

`clear` method is deprecated in `RealmResults` 0.89.1

I have used this method at some places in my code.
The latest docs doesn't have any updates about it.
What is the new method to delete all results from `Realm`?

Comment: Wouldn't `deleteAllFromRealm()` do the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `RealmResults.clear()` now throws UnsupportedOperationException. Use `RealmResults.deleteAllFromRealm()` instead.

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md